# Best way to handle different panels occupying same area

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this application:[image: myApplication]

I want to change the marked area when the user is clicked one of the navBarItems (like Microsoft OUTLOOK). I've been doing some research and a lot of people said that I can add several panels and show/hide them when user is clicked a navBarItem. But the area will contain a lot of gridviews and a lot of other controls. I don't know if I want to initialize all of them when application starts because it's gonna be hard on the cpu and memory to keep all the controls running at the same time. And I don't think it's an elegant solution for this kind of situation. But if I choose to initialize controls when user is clicked to corresponding navBarItem, it's gonna be laggy for the user.

What is the best design approach for this situation?

PS: I can use commercial libraries too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does not necessarily have to be laggy. If you show the screen first and then populate the data in the background it may not look too bad for the user. Also, once a particular screen is initialized you might keep it in memory so subsequent times user navigates to it it will be faster.

Also, look at what data you are loading into each control.  Is some of the data the same?  Can you preload some of the data in the background and keep it around?

Do you have a lot of drop down lists?  If so, can you prepopulate or cache some of the drop down list data to improve the performance?

Is there one or two of the panels that will be used a large majority of the time?  If so you could  preload these panels so the user has a better experience for the panels they will most often navigate to.

Background processing to load data will make your code more complex but that is going to be the best way to get good response time from your app.

[Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231635-how-can-i-use-a-backgroundworker-in-my-winforms-application/page__st__15) is an example of running a background thread from the UI using Task.

And another [one](http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2007/04/04/implementing-multi-threading-in-winforms-using-the-backgroundworker-class/) using the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: If I keep initialized screens in memory, it's going to be 10+ gridviews with tons of data in the memory plus other controls. I don't think it's efficient.

Comment: I am not saying populate them all at the same time, populate them as the user navigates to them, but do the data load in the background.  That will display the screen more quickly and give the user a better experience.  If the controls take up too much memory then throw them away when the user navigates to another panel.  If not then keep them around so the second time a user navigates to it they will have a better experience.

Comment: So you are saying that stick to the use of multiple panels with hide/show functionality but do some tricks for better user experience and memory management?

Comment: Yes, I also updated my answer to include a couple links to give you a better idea of the type of background processing possible.  There are other ways as well depending on the version of .Net you are using.  These are two of the more common ways.

Comment: Okay, I'll check them out!

Comment: Also, you could create User Controls instead of panels and instantiate/dispose instead of show/hide so you could free up the memory (although i suppose you could instantiate/dispose of panels as well if you choose but I like user controls.)